# How to do a count of characters

Tags: c++

I'm using Visual Studio 2013. I'm trying to do a text firstly and then count how many characters are in the text in total and print the number.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "math.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
 {

char text;


printf("enter text?%\n");

scanf_s("%d\n",text);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: text should be an array to store the characters, like text[256]; // In this case it work if the user does not enter more than 255 characters. Then lookup strlen in the help menu.

Comment: I'd like to vote this closed but zero effort isn't one of the listed options.

Comment: @user4581301 “Unclear what you are asking”'s description is “Please clarify your specific problem […]”. There clearly isn't a “specific problem” here…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a complete example here
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen

Comment: try including important parts of the post :)